# Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "widget/product/list.tpl" in core/smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1094

Tags: oxid

I just installed a OXID eSHOP COMMUNITY EDITION 4.10.2.

I copy paste my live site code into local server. Everything is working fine, but products not display.

It shows below error.

> Warning: Smarty error: unable to read resource: "widget/product/list.tpl" in core/smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1094

However it's working fine on live site. But not working on my local setup.

Answer (score 1):

Check if template file "widget/product/list.tpl" exists on your machine. Looks like you did not copy all the files from production server.

Comment: hi..thanks for your reply...it not included..after including its works.